# Time difference MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I want to compute the duration between two successive entries made by the same user, to be able to know how much time it takes the user to finish entering his data each time. I used the following query but it gives some negative values and duplicated results.

```
SELECT distinct u.name, u.firstname, c1.actenumber, c.actenumber,
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(c1.datecreation, c.datecreation)) as difference 
FROM user u, citizen c1, citizen c 
WHERE u.UTILID= c1.USERID 
  AND u.profil=0 
  AND c1.actenumber=c.actenumber-1
```

Comment: You know that DISTINCT works on the whole selected rows? You say negative values, what's the values for c1.datecreation and c.datecreation for those rows?

Comment: actually I am just trying to compute the difference between datecreation that are just two successive raws in the same table

Comment: Show us some sample data, the current output, and tell us what's wrong with it!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is you forgot to check that the two citizen rows are for the same citizen.  Otherwise you'll pick up rows for whomever happens to have an `actenumber-1`.

I've also cleaned up the query using JOIN syntax to make it clearer what the join logic is vs the WHERE constraints.

```
SELECT distinct u.name, u.firstname, c1.actenumber, c2.actenumber,
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(c1.datecreation, c2.datecreation)) as difference 
FROM user u
JOIN citizen c1
  ON u.UTILID = c1.USERID
JOIN citizen c2
  ON c1.USERID = c2.USERID          AND
     c1.actenumber=c2.actenumber-1
WHERE u.profil=0
```